# R replace string based on other string in column

Tags: r, tidyverse, stringr

I have column in dataframe which has following structure in the rows.

```
first cycle
first cycle
shifting cycle
shifting cycle
shifting cycle
2nd cycle 
2nd cycle
2nd cycle
shifting cycle
shifting cycle
3rd cycle
3rd cycle
```

I want to replace all rows with first entry of shifting cycle to shifting cycle 1 and 2nd entry of shifting cycle to shifting cycle 2. Basically it a string operation which I don' how to do it. Right I am doing it based on the value in other column but it is not appropriate to find the value in other column manually since value varies in many files.

My code

```
df$column <-str_replace(df$column, "Shifting cycle", "Shifting cycle 2")
df <- df %>% mutate(column = case_when(other_column ==30~ 'Shifting cycle 1' ,T~column))
```

so final output will be

```
first cycle
first cycle
shifting cycle 1
shifting cycle 1
shifting cycle 1
2nd cycle
2nd cycle 
2nd cycle
shifting cycle 2
shifting cycle 2
3rd cycle
3rd cycle
```

Comment: I have updated the question. Actually the shifting cycle rows were more than 1.

Comment: I have found the solution here it is ```df |> 
  dplyr::mutate(
    x = ifelse(
      x == "shifting cycle", 
      paste(x, cumsum(x == "shifting cycle" & dplyr::lag(x,default = "") != "shifting cycle")),
      x))```. Thanks to R4DS community on slack. X is the column with existing data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run Length Encoding to detect runs, generate a sequence to match number of rows in the dataframe and pass it through integer division by 2
(`1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 5 5` becomes `0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2` ).

The very first run will be coded as 0, to deal with those cases where dataset starts with a *shifting cycle* , we'll add `+ sc_runs$values[1]`, this avoids *shifting cycle 0*

```r
library(dplyr)
sc_str <- "shifting cycle"

sc_runs <- rle(df2$column == sc_str)
sc_runs
#> Run Length Encoding
#>   lengths: int [1:5] 2 3 3 2 2
#>   values : logi [1:5] FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE

sc <- rep(seq_along(sc_runs$lengths), sc_runs$lengths) %/% 2 + sc_runs$values[1]
sc
#>  [1] 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2

df2 %>%
  mutate(
    column =
      case_when(
        column == sc_str ~ paste(column, sc),
        TRUE ~ column
      )
  )
#> # A tibble: 12 × 1
#>    column          
#>    <chr>           
#>  1 first.cycle     
#>  2 first cycle     
#>  3 shifting cycle 1
#>  4 shifting cycle 1
#>  5 shifting cycle 1
#>  6 2nd cycle       
#>  7 2nd cycle       
#>  8 2nd cycle       
#>  9 shifting cycle 2
#> 10 shifting cycle 2
#> 11 3rd cycle       
#> 12 3rd cycle
```

Input data:

```
df2 <- tibble::tribble(
           ~column,
     "first.cycle",
     "first cycle",
  "shifting cycle",
  "shifting cycle",
  "shifting cycle",
       "2nd cycle",
       "2nd cycle",
       "2nd cycle",
  "shifting cycle",
  "shifting cycle",
       "3rd cycle",
       "3rd cycle"
  )

df <- tibble::tribble(
           ~column,
     "first.cycle",
     "first cycle",
  "shifting cycle",
       "2nd cycle",
       "2nd cycle",
       "2nd cycle",
  "shifting cycle",
       "3rd cycle",
       "3rd cycle"
  )
```

---

```r
# answer that was targeting the first variant of example data
df %>%
  mutate(
    column =
      case_when(
        column == "shifting cycle" ~ paste(column, cumsum(column == "shifting cycle")),
        TRUE ~ column
      )
  )
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: The shifting cycle rows are many so can you change the code . Right now it is giving me unique number for each row like Shifting cycle 1, Shifting cycle 2. Sorry if my question was not much clear

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(group = str_detect(cycles, "shifting cycle")) %>%
  mutate(cycles = case_when(
    group == TRUE ~ str_c(cycles, 1:n(), sep = " "),
    TRUE ~ cycles)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-group)

# A tibble: 9 × 1
  cycles          
  <chr>           
1 first cycle     
2 first cycle     
3 shifting cycle 1
4 2nd cycle       
5 2nd cycle       
6 2nd cycle       
7 shifting cycle 2
8 3rd cycle       
9 3rd cycle
```

Comment: The shifting cycle rows are many so can you change the code . Right it is giving me unique number for each row like Shifting cycle 1, Shifting cycle 2. Sorry if my question was not much clear